# How to loop through a Cherrio inside an async function and populate an outside variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-scraping, cheerio

I need to create an API that web scraps GitHub's repos getting the following data:

1. File name;
2. File extension;
3. File size (bytes, kbytes, mbytes, etc);
4. File number of lines;

I'm using Node with TypeScript so, to get the most out of it, I decided to create an interface called FileInterface, that has the four attributes mentioned above.

[image]

And of course, the variable is an array of that interface:

```
let files: FileInterface[] = [];
```

Let's take my own repo to use as an example: https://github.com/raphaelalvarenga/git-hub-web-scraping

[image]

So far so good.

I'm already pointing to the HTML's files section with request-promise dependency and storing them in a Cheerio variable so I can traverse through the "tr" tags to create a loop. As you might think, those "tr" tags represent each files/folders inside of a "table" tag (if you inspect the page, it can easily be found). The loop will fill a temp variable called:

```
let tempFile: FileInterface;
```

And at the end of every cycle of the loop, the array will be populated:

```
files.push(tempFile);
```

In GitHub repo's initial page, we can find the file names and their extension. But the size and total of lines, we can't. They are found when clicking on them to redirect to the file page. Let's say we clicked in README.md:

[image]

Ok, now we can see README.md has 2 lines and 91 Bytes.

My problem is, since this will take a long time, it needs to be an async function. But I can't handle the loop in Cheerio content inside the async function.

Things that I've tried:

1. Using map and each methods to loop through it and push in the array files;
2. Using await before the loop. I knew this one wouldn't actually work since it's just a loop that doesn't return anything;
3. The last thing I tried and believed that would work is Promise. But TypeScript accuses Promises return the "Promise unknown" type and I'm not allowed to populate the result in files arrays, since the types "unknown" and "FilesInterface[]" are not equal.

Below I'll put the code I created so far. I'll upload the repo in case you want to download and test (the link is at the beginning of this post), but I need to warn that this code is in the branch "repo-request-bad-loop". It's not in the master. Don't forget because the master branch doesn't have any of this that I mentioned =)

I'm making a request in Insomnia to the route "/" and passing this object:

```
{
   "action": "getRepoData",
   "url": "https://github.com/raphaelalvarenga/git-hub-web-scraping"
}
```

index-controller.ts file:

[image]

As you can see, it calls the getRowData file, the problematic one. And here it is.

getRowData.ts file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to help you, although I do not know typescript. I redid the getRowData function a bit and now it works for me:

```js
import cheerio from "cheerio";
import FileInterface from "../interfaces/file-interface";
import getFileRemainingData from "../routines/getFileRemaningData";

const getRowData = async (html: string): Promise<FileInterface[]> => {

    const $ = cheerio.load(html);    

    const promises: any[] = $('.files .js-navigation-item').map(async (i: number, item: CheerioElement) => {
        const tempFile: FileInterface = {name: "", extension: "", size: "", totalLines: ""};
        const svgClasses = $(item).find(".icon > svg").attr("class");
        const isFile = svgClasses?.split(" ")[1] === "octicon-file";

        if (isFile) {
            // Get the file name
            const content: Cheerio = $(item).find("td.content a");
            tempFile.name = content.text();

            // Get the extension. In case the name is such as ".gitignore", the whole name will be considered
            const [filename, extension] = tempFile.name.split(".");
            tempFile.extension = filename === "" ? tempFile.name : extension;

            // Get the total lines and the size. A new request to the file screen will be needed
            const relativeLink = content.attr("href")
            const FILEURL = `https://github.com${relativeLink}`;

            const fileRemainingData: {totalLines: string, size: string} = await getFileRemainingData(FILEURL, tempFile);

            tempFile.totalLines = fileRemainingData.totalLines;
            tempFile.size = fileRemainingData.size;
        } else {
            // is not file
        }

        return tempFile;
    }).get();

    const files: FileInterface[] = await Promise.all(promises);

    return files;
}

export default getRowData;
```

Comment: Hello Rustam D9RS. I'm studying your code right now. It works! Could you help me with some things you did? 1) Although you said you don't know TypeScript, do you think the const promises could be of type FileInterface[ ] since it will always return tempFile? 2) What does the .get( ) method you put at the end of the Cheerio loop does? 3) Why does the code waits for the loop since it doesn't have an await command? 4) What does the Promise.all(promises) will actually do? I'll be searching for those questions, but your answer would be very helpful, once it's linked to my case. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your first question.
2) Initially, a cheerio returns all objects in a collection wrapped in a special object of the cheerio class. The get method allows you to get an element without wrapping a cherio object.
3-4) The loop does not wait, it returns a Promise with the state "pending". Just Promise.all further allows you to wait until the status of each promise becomes "fulfilled".

Comment: Oh that's ok. I meant, if the loop returns tempFile in all cycles, and tempFile has a FileInterface type, then the const promises, which stores tempFile maybe could be an array of FileInterface. Thank you for your help. May I ask you one more thing? The person I got this task from told me they expect the first request to be long. But the subsequent ones shouldn't take too much time to be executed. Would you have anything in mind to handle such thing? Cache? Maybe session? I thought such rule weird at first, actually. But anyways, you already helped me a lot.

Comment: I hope I understand you correctly. The constant promises that are returned from the loop cannot be a FileInterface[] type, it will be a Promise<FileInterface>[] type. Regarding the second question, I think it means a cache that will need to be reset after a certain period of time, although this is strange, because we do not know when the repository will be updated.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again for the explanation. Wish you success.